# Zoom a div when it reaches certain area on webpage

Tags: jquery, html, touch, zooming

Below is part of my webpage

[image]

Am using jquery.touch.js to rotate this div.

HTML

```
<div class="trans-circle" id="circleDiv">
                        <div class="border-circle">
                            <div class="large-circle">
                                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. <br/><br/> Amirzai Sangin<br/>Minister of Communications<br/> Afghanisthan</p>

                            </div>
                            <div class="mini-circles1">
                                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. <br/><br/> John Campbell<br>President and CEO<br> Toranto Waterfront Revitalization Corportation</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mini-circles2">
                                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.<br/><br/> David Woolson<br/>President & CEO<br/> Walla Walla Chamber of Commerce</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mini-circles3">
                                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.<br/><br/> Lee Rainie<br/>Director<br/> Pew Research Center's Internet & American Life</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mini-circles4">
                                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.<br/><br/> Suvi Linden<br/>Member<br/> UN Commission for Digital Development</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Here am rotating this div with

```
$('#circleDiv').touch();
```

am not using pinching and dragging, only rotating.

Here when I rotate this, when small circle reaches position of bigger one I want to make it bigger like the bigger one, and when it moves out of the area it should become to its same size.

They all are divs, nothing else. How to achieve this? Any ideas?

Comment: you want help in making it big or in the logic to detect and make it big?

Comment: also provide a link to plugin page

Comment: I want to detect the position of div when it reached bigger circle area

Comment: link to plugin http://www.jqueryscript.net/mobile/jQuery-Plugin-For-Dragging-Rotating-Scaling-Elements-touch-js.html

Comment: whole app is for mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Just to show it big you can use css3 solution

Something like this

```
-ms-transform: scale(1); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scale(2); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: scale(1); /* Standard syntax */
```

create a class with this definition and add it to the div when required.